# Correct git operation to merge portion of a branch

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I have a git branch on which I am working on a feature that has necessitated changes to less related portions of the code.

I have had to stop development on this branch to work on a feature on another branch that the priority has changed for. This branch uses those portions of the code that where less related but changed on the first feature branch.

The first feature is not yet finished but it is stable up to a certain point in it's history, therefore I would like to merge all the changes up to that point with the master, but not any later commits, so that the new second feature branch uses the newer structure of that code that was changed that was less relevant in the first feature branch.

```
master A---B---C---D
            \
f1           E---F---G---H
```

In the example above H is not stable, but work up to G is and a new branch at D should build on this work instead of on the older work.

So to me it seems like I would want to merge at G onto D, with all of G's history... is that the correct idea?

What is such an operation called in git terminology? Maybe a cherry pick of a commit range from E to G?

Or maybe it is possible to branch my new branch from G and then rebase on D?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to merge G into D:

```
git checkout D
git merge G
```

Afterwards your history will look like this:

```
master A---B---C---D---M <-- HEAD
            \         /
f1           E---F---G---H
```

I'd advise against rebasing E-G on top of D, as it will be much harder later to merge H into master as well.

Comment: In your example at `git merge G`, G is just the commit hash? (sorry bit n00b to git still)